# What is Unity CmdDelegate

Tags: unity-game-engine, delegates, unity-networking

Can't find any example, that describe how to use CmdDelegate in Unity.
Unity scripting API have only one line in description: "Delegate for Command functions." Some pseudocode will help.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity and delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508359/unity-and-delegate)

Comment: From what I know, this is just delegate template to use internaly by Unity networking engine. If you check the `NetworkBehaviour` code, it has some registry for callbacks of `CmdDelegate` type.